# Как задать rootContext в qt5 для qml view?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qml, qt4

Я хочу совместить qml  и с++
пытаюсь сделать это примерно так :

```
auto Root = ui->rootObject();
//Соединяем C++ и QML, делая видимым функции С++ через элемент window 
ui->rootContext()->setContextProperty("window", this);
```

но у rootContext() нет метода setContexProperty как в qt4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте класс `QQmlApplicationEngine` в Qt5

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(...)
```